# Como desactivar un error de PHP intelephense

Tags: php, laravel, vscode

Estoy utilizando VSCode como editor y tengo la extensión de PHP intelephense, estoy usando Laravel 8 y en algunos casos la extensión de PHP me marca errores que no existen y se me hace molesto que me indique estos errores. Un caso muy concreto es cuando utilizo el `can`. La pregunta es si puedo desactivar o indicarle que ese supuesto error en especifico en realidad no lo es.

Gracias

Comment: En la opcion de Extensiones (shift + cmd + x) podes buscar la extension y deshabilitarla.

Comment: La idea no es deshabilitar toda la extensión sino solo indicarle a la extensión que ese "error" no existe.

Comment: Sin más datos es difícil, pero en la configuración de intelephense puedes activar y desactivar las bibliotecas de php que quieres que te monitorice la extensión y si no tienes activada la biblioteca que estas usando te mostrará el error.